# Modulo function and variable domain

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Here is a simple CLPFD relation:

```
1 #= 81 mod X.
```

This returns:

```
X in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
81 mod X#=1.
```

Unless my math is completely incorrect, shouldn't the domain of `X` be `-80.. -1\/1..80`?

Comment: Regarding the equation A mod B = C, if |A|>|C|, then |B|<=|A|-|C|; if |A|=|C|, then there are infinitely many solutions; if |A|<|C|, then there are no solutions.

Comment: Since the sign of C is equal to the sign of B unless one of them is zero, you can further treat them that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first:

> Is there a *mistake* in the constraint solver?

**No**(t necessarily), because all admissible solutions are still contained in the domain that is deduced, and no wrong solutions are reported. The domain that you deduced is a proper *subset* of what the solver reports.

> Does the constraint solver propagate as well as it could in this case?

**No**, obviously not, as your stronger bounds already show. In fact, the admissible domain is even smaller than what you deduced: `X in 2..80` would *also* be valid, because `X` can definitely **not** be negative, and it also **cannot** be equal to 1.

**Exercise**: Is `X in 2..80` the *smallest* (with respect to set inclusion) domain that can be deduced in this case? Why (not)? And in what, if any, sense *is* it minimal?

> So, what is going on here?

The explanation is rather easy: Implementing `(mod)/2`, `(rem)/2`, `(div)/2` and—to somewhat lesser extent—even `(*)/2` in such a way that they propagate *as much as possible* in all cases is **brutally difficult** to get right, and was clearly not done in this case.

> Do we have to live with this shortcoming?

**No**, because we can *improve the constraint solver* to handle such cases too! That is, we can add logic so that it propagates *more strongly*! Doing this elegantly and correctly is an *unsolved problem* in general, and subject of *active research*. See for example [**Finite Domain Constraint Solver Learning**](https://lallouet.users.greyc.fr/Publications_files/ijcai03.pdf), the references included therein, and several other papers. Of course, the dream would be to somehow derive the propagation directly from the **specification** of these operations, which is at least decades away. Until then, such issues are found and improved rather *ad hoc*.

Comment: Thank you. Side question: is it easier to implement them in such a way that they at least propagate to **finite domains** that contain the smallest domains? If so are the propagation mechanisms of CLP(FD) still currently worked on to reach that goal?

Comment: Yes, to both questions. It *is* generally at least somewhat easier to reach at least finite domains. Often though, when you really think about what finite bound can be applied, it is only a little more difficult to derive the strongest one. And yes, CLP(FD) implementations get stronger all the time in this regard (for finite as well as infinite cases!), typically triggered by reports of users who need precisely the cases that do not *yet* work sufficiently well. CLP(FD) solvers in general are still under massive developments in many ways, and often get better due to constructive user feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't know what I am talking about, I just wanted to see for myself what happens, and thought it might be useful to share.

With SWI-Prolog and library(clpfd):

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- 1 #= 81 rem X.
X in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
81 rem X#=1.

?- 1 #= 81 mod X.
X in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
81 mod X#=1.

?- 1 #= 81 - X * (81 // X ).
X in -80.. -1\/1..80,
X*_G1053#=80,
81//X#=_G1053,
_G1053 in -80.. -1\/1..80.
```

Strange, isn't the expression in the last example supposed to be how modulo division is defined?

If you take Gnu-Prolog (`mod` is not directly supported):

```
| ?- 1 #= 81 rem X.

X = _#4(2..80)

yes
| ?- 1 #= 81 - X * (81 // X).

no
```

Hmm. What if you just **reorder the expression**:

```
| ?- 1 #= 81 - (81 // X) * X.

X = _#4(2..80)

yes
```

Conclusion: yes, it seems that writing a good CLP(FD) library is indeed not easy. One could even be left with the impression that these libraries exhibit emergent behaviors that the authors are not always fully aware of.

Comment: You can turn this into a level playing field by imposing the restrictions that hold for GNU Prolog also for SWI Prolog. If you try, with SWI-Prolog, the query: `1 #= 81 - X * (81 // X ), X #>= 0.` (note that `X` is now restricted to non-negative integers, which is what holds in GNU Prolog), then you get `X in 2..80` also with SWI-Prolog. Also in SWI-Prolog, please see the comments in the source code that clearly show in which cases the solver *could* propagate more, but currently *doesn't*. These situations are typically marked with comments like `TODO: stronger propagation`.

Comment: @mat As I said, I don't really know what I am talking about. I didn't know, for example, that in Gnu Prolog's CLP(FD) all variables are non-negative integers. Either way: if switching the operands of a multiplication makes the difference between "no" and a useful answer, that's bad. Similarly, if re-writing the constraint using the textbook definition gives different results, that's a bit fishy too. I also understand that just spewing out my top-level interaction without explaining _why_ this is happening is not that useful to anyone.

Comment: I think it is very useful! I only wanted to add that these cases *are* often known to CLP(FD) authors, but either were found too hard to implement correctly, or not deemed important enough (yet) to invest the time that is necessary to do it, in comparison to things that are more urgent. I think what you are doing is good: It shows that there is a lot left to do in CLP(FD) implementations, such as preserving the properties you mention. In my experience, many users are not even aware that these libraries are still under such active developments, and that constructive user input is so important.

Comment: @mat Well, then, you will allow me one more observation: in library(clpfd), there is both `mod` and `rem`. However, there is only truncated integer division, `//`, but no floored integer division.

Comment: `?- X #= -5 div 3.` yields: `-2`. Apparently, not all available features are considered ripe for the official documentation yet...

Comment: @mat "Use the source, Luke" ;-)

Comment: @mat If you compare a library (or any software) that doesn't promise much and delivers it all to  a library that promises a lot and has rough edges: well, both have their benefits, dangers, and modes of use.

Comment: Please be more explicit: Do you mean one of the libraries promises what it not fully delivers? I have checked both documentations and did not find an instance of this.

Comment: @mat No, what I mean is that CLPFD is too difficult to expect any implementation to magically have it "all covered". This is of course not ideal _for some use cases_.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But it is what many users are doing: They expect the CLPFD system to not only fully subsume declarative integer arithmetic, but also to magically make their whole program completely different to what they have written. That is obviously completely out of scope of such systems. I sometimes wish that CLP(FD) users would behave more like users of other software: If there is a feature you need, you file an issue and hope that someone fixes it, or look into the code and contribute the patch yourself. Instead, what I see are many users trying out CLP(FD) and then saying:

Comment: "What a dumb system: It does not relieve me of actually writing the whole program!" From this, they then conclude: "So I should not use constraints at all.". I literally have never seen, *anywhere*, more illogical behaviour of users than what I have seen in the logic programming community.

Comment: @mat This is getting a bit out of the scope of the question and the answer, but: CLP(FD), other libraries that come with Prolog, and indeed Prolog the programming language all promise a bit too much to the uninitiated. This is not a fault of the libraries or the language or the implementations, it is a textbook case of a message getting garbled because the sender and the receiver are not synchronized.

Comment: @mat PS: I think it was Steve Yegge (I almost miss his drunken rants) who talked about this. One shouldn't put too much effort in making a tool easy to pick up. After all, everyone is a beginner for a while, but will spend more time being an expert, if they put the effort to get past the beginner stage. In this context, one has to be especially careful not to mislead beginners: they are bound to be overly optimistic when picking up a new tool.

Comment: I agree with what you first wrote first, not with the PS. Take a dancing instructor: Sometimes, the instructor will tell you to do motions that are completely exaggerated. You try to perform the motion, and it feels grossly excessive. When you tell the instructor: "This does not feel right! It feels like I'm doing too much, and it looks strange." The instructor then says: "That's because before I overstated how to make the motion, you did not make the motion at all. Now that I told you to exaggerate it, you are making 20% of the motion I eventually want you to do, in a 5-10 years horizon."

Comment: @Boris: `rem` and `mod` differ exactly for cases with negative numbers...

Comment: @false Yes, which is why I thought it's relevant to point out that at the moment floored integer division is not officially supported.